# $\mathbb{Q}(\alpha, \sqrt 2)$ = $\mathbb{Q}(\alpha \sqrt 2)$, where $\alpha$ is a root of $ x^3 −x^2 + 1$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory, extension-field

> $\mathbb{Q}(\alpha, \sqrt 2)$ = $\mathbb{Q}(\alpha \sqrt 2)$, where $\alpha$ is a root of $ x^3 −x^2 + 1$?
> Also, $\mathbb{Q(\alpha, \sqrt 2)} = \mathbb{Q}(\alpha + \sqrt 2)$?

I know that the polynomial is irreducible over $\mathbb{Q}$, and also that to solve this exercise I must use the fact that $\alpha = -\alpha^4 + \alpha^2 + 1$.

Comment: This is not clear.  Why write $\mathbb Q(2\sqrt 2)$?  That's the same as $\mathbb Q(\sqrt 2)$, so the claim would be that $\alpha \in \mathbb Q(\sqrt 2)$, which is false.

Comment: @lulu is correct, I have already made the correction to the question. $\mathbb{Q}(\alpha,\sqrt 2)=\mathbb{Q}(\alpha \sqrt 2)$

Comment: The fact you know you must use seems incorrect.

Answer (score 1):

Let $\beta=\alpha\sqrt{2}$.

It is clear that $\mathbb Q(\alpha\sqrt2)\subseteq \mathbb Q(\alpha,\sqrt2)$, so we will show the reverse inclusion.

We can rewrite the equation $\alpha=-\alpha^2+\alpha^2+1$ as:

$$\alpha=\frac{\beta^4}4+\frac{\beta^2}2+1$$

Thus $\alpha \in \mathbb Q(\beta)$. Then since $\sqrt{2}=\beta/\alpha \in \mathbb Q(\beta)$ as well, it follows that $\mathbb Q(\alpha,\sqrt2)\subseteq \mathbb Q(\alpha\sqrt2)$. Thus we are done.

Comment: It has a typo, one $\alpha^2$ should be $\alpha^4$